# plotly in r 3d arrows between two points

Tags: r, 3d, arrows, r-plotly

I would like to draw arrows between two points. This is the problem, where I made the three arrows with a graphical program to explain my problem.

[image]

That is my source code:

```
require(plotly)

a <- c(5,16,16,17,18,23,25,27,37,42,5)
b <- c(13,12,26,15,14,6,10,22,14,25,17)
c <- c(12,14,25,26,8,9,27,30,31,26.5,12)

ap <- c(5,12,16,17,11,23,25,27,37,21.5,5)
bp <- c(13,12,26,15,14,6,10,22,14,12.5,17)
cp <- c(12,14,25,26,8,9,27,30,31,26,12)

rnn <- c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U4", "U5", "U6", "U7", "U8", "U9", "U10", "U11")

m <- list( symbol = 200, size = 8, line = list( color = toRGB("yellow"), width = 2 ) ) 
m1 <- list( symbol = "triangle", color="black", sizemod = "diameter", size = 5, line = list( color = "black", width = 2 ) )

plot_ly(x = ap, y = bp, z = cp) %>%

  add_trace(marker = m1, type = "scatter3d", mode = "text+markers", 
        name = "projected", linetypes = NULL, text = rnn) %>%
  add_trace(x = a, y = b, z = c, marker = m, type = "scatter3d", mode = "text+markers", 
        name = "original", linetypes = NULL, text = rnn)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What is `marker = m1`?

Comment: Sorry ...  
     m <- list(
      symbol = 200,
      size = 8,
     line = list(
      color = toRGB("yellow"),
      width = 2 )
     )

   m1 <- list(
     symbol = "triangle",
     color="black",
     sizemod = "diameter",
     size = 5,
     line = list(
       color = "black",
       width = 2 )  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you could try this:

```
aaa <- c(16, 12)
bbb <- c(12, 12)
ccc <- c(14, 14)

aaaa <- c(18, 11)
bbbb <- c(14, 14)
cccc <- c(8, 8)

aaaaa <- c(42, 21.5)
bbbbb <- c(25, 12.5)
ccccc <- c(26.5, 26)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = aaa, y = bbb, z = ccc, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines", 
            name = "lines", showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x = aaaa, y = bbbb, z = cccc, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines", 
            name = "lines", showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x = aaaaa, y = bbbbb, z = ccccc, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines", 
            name = "lines", showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x = ap, y = bp, z = cp, marker = m1, type = "scatter3d", mode = "text+markers", 
            name = "projected", linetypes = NULL, text = rnn) %>%
  add_trace(x = a, y = b, z = c, marker = m, type = "scatter3d", mode = "text+markers", 
            name = "original", linetypes = NULL, text = rnn)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks MLavoie, it works well. It really has a small problem: this is part of a procedure, where I do not know how many units I will have, but apart from this, this is a very good solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @user10117816 I would appreciate if you could accept the answer, by checking the mark. thanks.